# Using clipboard through SSH in vim

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vim

I have Ubuntu 11.04 desktop and a 11.04 VPS server.

After replacing `vim` with `vim-gtk` (I don't need GUI though), I'm able to use the system's clipboard in `vim`. I'd like to use the same feature in Ubuntu server, but it looks like it doesn't work with `ssh -X`.

Is there some way I can enable that feature or do I need to use `nano` for that?

Comment: related for windows host: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313262/copying-stuff-from-vim-running-in-putty/4313348#4313348

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The "clipboard" is a feature of X11, so you will need to enable "X11 forwarding" for the SSH connection in "trusted" mode:

```
$ ssh -Y myserver
```

(By default, X11 is forwarded in "untrusted" mode, which is somewhat *too* restrictive. `-Y` disables the restrictions.)

Also make sure the server has `xauth` and a X11-capable version of *vim* installed. You can use `xsel -o` and `xsel -o -b` to verify that the clipboard can be accessed.

---

To make it permanent, add the following to your local `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myserver
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Comment: I'm using vim-gtk in server and I can see using "vim --version" that X11 is enabled. There is nothing about xauth through. This is what I get: $ xsel -o
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Success

Comment: "sudo apt-get install xauth" did the trick.

Comment: For whomever it is useful for: this worked for me, but only with the `+` register, not the `*` register.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Does doing this mean you're actually using X-based vim, and not the command line text based Vim?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: No. If you run `vim`, you still get the text-based Vim – which just has minimal X11 support for accessing the clipboard and such.

Comment: This affects Neovim too. With a regular SSH connection if you do `:echo has('clipboard')` you get `0`. However once you connect with `ssh -Y` then `:echo has('clipboard')` gives you `1`. I got the `has('clipboard') check from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489440/327074

Comment: Could you extend the _which is somewhat too restrictive_ bit? What's the problem with just `-X`/untrusted mode? Seems to work fine.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of enable `ForwardX11` and `ForwardX11Trusted` ?